# I am seeing unexpected input in my buffer after socket reading

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to get some json data from a server, but my program sometimes prints unexpected string although I check it multiple times to verify it has correct beginning and ending.

These are my send and read functions from the web server:

```
    int total_to_send = request.size();
    int sent;
    int total_sent = 0;
    while(total_sent < total_to_send) {
        sent = send(_socket, &request.data()[total_sent], total_to_send - total_sent, 0);
        if(sent <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        total_sent += sent;
    }
    if(sent <= 0) {
        printf("[Thread #%i] Error occurred when sending request... (%i/%i, %i @ %s)\n", total_sent, total_to_send, sent, path.c_str());
        break;
    }

    int read;
    int total_read = 0;
    while(true) {
        read = recv(_socket, &buffer[total_read], sizeof(char) * 1024, 0);
        total_read += read;
        if(read <= 0)
            break;
        if(total_read > 0 && buffer[total_read - 1] == '}')
            break;
    }
    if(read < 0 || total_read == 0) {
        printf("[Thread #%i] Error occurred when reading response... (%i, %i @ %s)\n", ThreadID, read, total_read, path.c_str());
        break;
    }
```

The buffer is a `char buffer[1024000];`. I am pretty sure the buffer has enough space for the response.

I try to verify that the response has the correct beginning and ending with the following:

```
    if(buffer[total_read - 1] != '}') {
        printf("[Thread #%i] Invalid response from the server... ('%c', %i, %i @ %s)\n", ThreadID, buffer[total_read - 1], read, total_read, path.c_str());
        break;
    }

    int start_pos = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < total_read; ++i) {
        if(buffer[i] == '{') {
            start_pos = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(start_pos == -1) {
        printf("[Thread #%i] Invalid response from the server... (%i, %i @ %s)\n", ThreadID, read, total_read, path.c_str());
        break;
    }

    if(step == 0) {
        static const char NonExistingResource[11] = "Not found.";
        if((total_read - start_pos) == 10) {
            int s = 0;
            for(int c = 0; c < 11; ++c) {
                if(NonExistingResource[c] == buffer[start_pos + c]) {
                    ++s;
                }
            }
            if(s == 10) {
                printf("[Thread #%i] The resource %i does not exist...\n", ThreadID, StartID);
                step = 9;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything works as expected - well, at least, most of the time it does. I am adding a little bit more information to my buffer, and then attempt to write it:

```
    buffer[total_read] = '\n';
    buffer[start_pos - 1] = '#';

    fwrite(&buffer[start_pos - 1], sizeof(char), (total_read - start_pos) + 2, file);
```

The problem begins afterwards. 99% of the time I am writing a valid json to the file (e.g. `#{"id":3,"numbers":[1, 3, 7],"time":1323423610}`), but in the remaining 1%, my code writes the entire read content. And this content follows the previous line without adding any line breaks or the #. For example,

```
#{"id":1,"numbers":[1, 3, 7],"time":1323423610}
#{"id":2,"numbers":[2, 4, 8],"time":1323423610}
#{"id":3,"numbers":[9],"time":1323423610}HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 88
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Fri, 10 Jul 2020 07:53:42 GMT
Server: openresty
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, Retry-After, Content-Length, Content-Range
Cache-Control: public, max-age=21600
x-memc: MISS, STORE
x-memc-key: 8c68004d1219af73acc5312e3fdf554e
x-memc-age: 0
x-memc-expires: 21600
Last-Modified: 2020-04-11 11:27:09 +0000
X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront
Age: 4478

{"id":4,"numbers":[5],"time":1323423610}
#{"id":5,"numbers":[6],"time":1323423610}
```

Now, my code is obviously in a loop. It send multiple requests using the same socket, and recreate the socket when the server returns an error or the requests fail. Other than that, I never attempt to change buffer, except resetting it sometimes but it should not cause any problems because I am not editing it between the read and fwrite.

Also, I encounter with this at random times. Sometimes, the program runs as expected and outputs what I want, and sometimes, it just puts the entire response there! I cannot find a pattern to follow.

By the way, the code is meant to work with multiple threads simultaneously, but each thread has its own socket and FILE*, so no other thread is interfering with the writing process. Sometimes, some threads does this and some does not, although I tell the to send equal number of requests.

Any help/ideas is well appreciated people!

Comment: Maybe so obvious that you didn't bother to state it, but does each thread have it's own `buffer`?

Comment: @john yes, each thread has its own buffer

Comment: Seems likely that threading is part of the problem. I would test with a single thread to find out for sure if that is the case.

Comment: @john Unfortunately, it is not. I tried calling the function directly from main() and ended up with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is an issue, but if the socket returns an error (`-1`), you add `-1` to `total_read`, then break out of the loop.

This:

```
while(true) {
    read = recv(_socket, &buffer[total_read], sizeof(char) * 1024, 0);
    total_read += read;
    if(read <= 0)
        break;
    if(total_read > 0 && buffer[total_read - 1] == '}')
        break;
}
```

Better:

```
while(true) {
    read = recv(_socket, &buffer[total_read], sizeof(char) * 1024, 0);
    if(read <= 0)
        break;
    total_read += read;
    if(total_read > 0 && buffer[total_read - 1] == '}')
        break;
    buffer[total_read] = '\0'; // null terminate, makes debugging easier
}
```

Further, it seems like you are actually making an HTTP request, but doing something extremely hacky to discover the start/end of the response's content body.  (And doing something even more hacky to detect a 404 Not Found resposne).  Any legit HTTP client will MIME parse the lines of headers, find the Content-Length header, and reference that value for how many bytes to read after the blank line.  Have you considered using a real HTTP library like Boost Beast or libCurl ?

Otherwise, I suspect you have some combination of a socket error and an uninitialized variable that's causing you to read from a random place in the buffer.

Comment: Actually, this is in a while loop and the last line of the loop increases an integer indicating that the loop was successful. Therefore, breaking the loop tells me that something went wrong. And when I create the socket, I check if it has been created successfully, otherwise, it prints an error.

I tried using Boost::Asio but ended up with the same thing. And, I did not want to spend time on parsing the headers, because I am expecting a certain format in each response.

Comment: `and the last line of the loop increases an integer indicating` - But you didn't show that part. You just put a portion of your code instead of the complete picture.  If you can post a [mcve], then the bug will more easily be spotted.  And if you had the same bug with Asio, then that implies the bug is not in your socket code - probably some other mis-initialized variable in your loop that influences `start_pos`.  Please update your question with a full repro example (not just a code snippit).  Until then, I still stand by my answer.

Comment: Also, one day, and perhaps not tomorrow, something is going to change on the service where one of those headers auto-generated suddenly contains a `{`.  And then your client code is going to fall over and break.  I'm not sure if this is person project you are working on, or for your job, but I implore you - DONT PARSE HTTP LIKE THIS.  These are how bugs, or worse - security bugs, sneak in.

Comment: And if can't convince you not to use a real http client library like Boost Beast that will literally deliver the full string of the body in a single callback, then consider doing this:  Parse your response from end to start.  The last character in your buffer should be `}`.  So after validating that, scan backwards in `buffer` until you hit the first `{`.  That might make your manual parsing simpler and less error prone.